# How do I iterate arguments of a macros in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a macro that fills first elements of a vector with a fixed size. The rest of elements should be zero. I wrote:

```
const SIZE: usize = 3;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyVec {
    data: [f32; SIZE]
}

macro_rules! my_vec {
    ($($x:expr),*) => [{
        let mut data: [f32; SIZE] = [0.0; SIZE];
        for (i, e) in x.enumerate() {
            data[i] = e;
        }
        MyVec { data }
    }]
}

fn main() {
    let v = my_vec![1.0, 2.0];
    println!("{:?}", v);  // must be MyVec { data: [1.0, 2.0, 0.0] }
}
```

It looks like I try to iterate the arguments in a wrong way. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this. The code inside the `$(...)*` will be expanded for each matches.

```
const SIZE: usize = 3;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyVec {
    data: [f32; SIZE],
}

macro_rules! my_vec {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut data: [f32; SIZE] = [0.0; SIZE];
            let mut index = 0;
            $(
                #[allow(unused_assignments)]
                {
                    data[index] = $x;
                    index = index + 1;
                }
            )*
            MyVec { data }
        }
    };
}

fn main() {
    let v = my_vec![1.0, 2.0];
    println!("{:?}", v); // print MyVec { data: [1.0, 2.0, 0.0] }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. Why do I get the warning in the line `index = index + 1` with the text `warning: value assigned to 'index' is never read`?

Comment: @Fomalhaut This will expand to `let mut index = 0; data[index] = …; index = index + 1; data[index] = …; index = index + 1; data[index] = …; index = index + 1;`, the last `index = index + 1` being the one that creates a warning. I've edited the answer to ignore the warning.